# Which SQL statement is better?

Tags: sql, sql-update

Which Statement is better?

```
Update tableA set field1 = @AAA
where fieldB = 12345
and fieldC = 'Ask'
and fieldA <> @AAA
```

Or

```
Update tableA set field1 = @AAA
where fieldB = 12345
and fieldC = 'Ask'
```

Assume only less than 5 rows match the criteria, is it redundant to add fieldA <> @AAA?  It may slow down search, however it filter out those records don't need to be updated. So I don't know if I should always add this condition.

Comment: Of course it's better to update less rows even if the result is the same (  consider possible triggers f.e. ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are not the same.  The correct first query should take `NULL`s into account.  This is more cumbersome than it sounds:

```
Update tableA
    set field1 = @AAA
    where fieldB = 12345 and
          fieldC = 'Ask' and
          (fieldA <> @AAA or fieldA is null and @AAA is not null or
           fieldA is not null and @AAA is null
          );
```

As mentioned in the comments and in other answer, limiting the number of rows is "better" in the sense that the query performs better.  This would be particularly true if you had an index with the three columns, such as `(fieldB, fieldC, fieldA)`.  Then, the engine can determine which rows to update using the index -- perhaps saving on reading a bunch of rows.

Note: databases differ in whether an update "actually" occurs when the values are the same.  That is, whether the update gets logged and whether or not triggers are activated.

Comment: Yeah you are right I need to consider null values. However could you explain more about 'whether the update gets logged and whether or not triggers are activated.'? I don't get it well.

Comment: Such details depend on the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use the first query because it will update minimum records and no unnecessary row will be updated from this query.